# Why is distplot changing the range of values plotted?

Tags: python, seaborn

I have an array of values for which I am trying to fit a probability density function. I plotted the histogram using distplot as shown below:

```
x = [  17.56,
 162.52,
 172.58,
 160.82,
 182.14,
 165.86,
 242.06,
 135.76,
 122.86,
 230.22,
 208.66,
 271.36,
 122.68,
 188.42,
 171.82,
 102.30,
 196.40,
 107.38,
 192.35,
 179.66,
 173.30,
 254.66,
 176.12,
 75.365,
 135.78,
 103.66,
 183.50,
 166.08,
 207.66,
 146.22,
 151.19,
 172.20,
 103.41,
 133.93,
 186.48,]
sns.distplot(x)
```

and the plot looks like this:
[image]

My minimum value in the array is 17 and maximum value is around 250 so I don't understand the range on the x-axis in the figure as I have not added any arguments either. Does `sns.displot` standardize the data before plotting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [kde curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) fits many gaussian normal curves over the data points. Such a normal curve has an infinite tail, which here is cut off when it gets close enough to zero height.

Note that [`sns.distplot` has been deprecated](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) since seaborn 0.11, and replaced by (in this case) `sns.histplot(..., kde=True)`. The [new kdeplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html) has a parameter `cut=` which defaults to zero, cutting the curve at the data limits (`cut` is one of the `kde_kws` in `histplot`: `sns.histplot(x, kde=True, kde_kws={'cut': 0}).` ).

```py
import seaborn as sns

x = [17.56, 162.52, 172.58, 160.82, 182.14, 165.86, 242.06, 135.76, 122.86, 230.22, 208.66, 271.36, 122.68, 188.42,
     171.82, 102.30, 196.40, 107.38, 192.35, 179.66, 173.30, 254.66, 176.12, 75.365, 135.78, 103.66, 183.50, 166.08,
     207.66, 146.22, 151.19, 172.20, 103.41, 133.93, 186.48]
sns.histplot(x, kde=True)
```

[image: histplot with kde, cut off to data limits]

Comment: Thank you! I just realised the same, I used `sns.histplot(x, color="orange", kde=True, stat="density", linewidth=0 ) and compared my plot and realised its only coz the curve is extending to beyond 0.
`